# Find the volume enclosed by the paraboloid (triple integral)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the volume enclosed by the paraboloid $x=y^2+2z^2$ and the plane $x=5$
To do this we take $$\int_0^5 \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^\sqrt{x} \int_{-\sqrt{\frac{x-y^2}{2}}}^{\sqrt{\frac{x-y^2}{2}}} \,\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Is this correct?
Then using cylindrical coordinates we use substitution $y=r\sin t$, $z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}r\cos t$, so $\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}r$, and the limits are $0 \leq r \leq \sqrt{x}$, $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$, $0 \leq x \leq 5$. Is this correct also?

Comment: Please format properly using MathJax

Comment: This might prove helpful :)

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Everything is correct except for the jacobian, $dz dy = r/\sqrt 2 dt dr$.